# postgres comma in column name, import issue

Tags: postgresql, csv, import

I got some data I need to update in a table. I am using pgadmin3 import tool csv GUI.
My issue is how to setup the import setting.

The data structure is pretty bad with column name like `"width, inside" integer` and its not much I can do about it atm.

Can I ignore the comma (,) inside the quote of the column name?

The error I get is

```
"ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
CONTEXT: COPY mytable, line 2, column width integer, inside: ""
```

So it is interpreting the comma inside the quote in I way I try to avoid.

Extra:
I have put '\N' in the NULL option because many of the records is just empty in the csv file like so "", "", "",...

Snippet of CSV file and table structure

```
create table a (
  "Width, inside" integer,
  "Area" character varying(50),
  "Year" date
)

"width, inside", "Area", "Year"
"3","sub",""
```

Comment: use double quotes for column name

Comment: Post the first lines of the csv file.

Comment: Your issue is not the column name, it seems it is already quoted well. One of your rows contains an empty value `""` for that column, which is not a valid integer. (note: `\N` is the default `NULL` value in `text` format, however in `CSV` format, the unquoted empty strings will became `NULL` by default; you can change the behavior with the `NULL` option of the [`COPY` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)).

Comment: Yeah you are right, that is what happen. However, how to set emtyp null integer as default instead of empty text values "" is not clear to me. This turn out more complicated that I was hoping for.

Comment: Please provide the `COPY` statement you are trying to execute and some sample rows (with header as well) from the CSV. If you are COPYing with `CSV` format, you should try with rows like: `,,,"data",,234,,,,` (Note the commas after each other: between every comma next to each other, there will be an SQL `NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

```
create table a ("column, comma" int);
select "column, comma" from a;
```

this won't raise exception.

Definitively putting comments with orthography in column name is a bad practice. I would rename it to something reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The table structure is already in the format you suggested. But it is still failing the csv import to that table. To me it seem that the import interpreter find my (,) in column name and breaks it and are not treating it as part of the complete column name despite the quotes.

Comment: so replace all `width, inside` to `"width, inside"` in your csv

Answer (score 0):

one way is to change the delimiter from , to say ; . You can do a replace manually in the text/csv file and in the import screen specify ; as the delimiter (I guess your client should have it - look at a tab called misc option or something similar to it)

Also postgres might have other issues with the , in middle of a string - which could be handled by replacing the double quotes with $$

thus this might work :

```
    $$width, inside$$; $$Area$$; $$Year$$
```